# How to receive a user input from UI, place it in a python code in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, nlp, word-embedding

I have to receive a user input from UI and have to place it in as mentioned below. I am using flask to do this.

```
def generate():
words=[]
with open("**content to be received from user**", 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
```

Comment: Flask is a web framework. Its intended way of communication are webforms and AJAX/REST calls. On the other hand it is not common and not very secure to allow direct file operations from the web.

Comment: Okay. Can you please suggest me a way to implement such a use case?